# Laravel 5 mysql connection with MAMP in mac

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, php-5.5, laravel-5.1

I have installed laravel 5 in my local in Mac. I am using MAMP for mysql connection and it is showing error when I am trying to submit the form.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
```

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your Database for project  in MySQL ? 
And setting username and password in .env file ?

Please check your database setting in `config/database.php`.

Comment: Yes I have created database and I have changed everything in config/database.php

'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'talentpool',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

and I have renamed .env file. Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: I think you should set password for mysql root account